# Record video chunks

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, android-camera2, mediarecorder

I have a problem with video saving. The task is writing a video file every three seconds during video recording. The problem is that there is a time lag between video files for about 0.5 seconds.

I have already tried MediaRecorder, MediaCodec with MediaMuxer (grafika google samples) and FFMpeg so far and still have no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions? Any ideas are really appreciated!

Comment: can you use `Continuous capture` from grafika.?? it's take 7 second video file.

Comment: @Ali I've modified it so it does capture 3-seconds chunks but I ran into new problems.

1. It does not record sound and I need to
2. Sometimes it looses i-frames in start of new file and video starts from black screen

Comment: *It does not record sound*. There is no sound in grafika. @fadden suggest for audio follow this link: https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest.  and sry i have no idea about second point.